# meaning of gcm server response?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I've implemented GCM on both Server and Client. 
I have 2 android phones as clients to test the push notification feature in my app. 
The GCM is working fine but I found a strange behavior.
I logged in at my second phone with same ID to test that both phones can get the same push 
message. Then I sent the push notification and absolutely it worked! 
But the problem was that my second phone got the same push message again.

I couldn't find any clue from my registration ID DB (there are only 2 registration IDs). 
So, I checked the GCM server response which is below.
Here is the question. What is the meaning of success count? 
Does it mean that my server sent the push request 2 times?

{"multicast_id":6323573331427315745,"success":2,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1385545930612944%6d7e418ff9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1385545930613926%6d7e418ff9fd7ecd"}]} >>> {"status":"success","login":true,"errorMsg":"","result":{"result":XXX}}

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

The server response means you sent the same message to two registration IDs, and Google's GCM server accepted your messages for delivery and either delivered or will attempt to deliver them to the two devices. It doesn't matter you signed in with the same user in both devices. Each device has its own registration ID for your app.

Answer (score 1):

Please check [GCM HTTP connection response format](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#response).

`success`->Number of messages that were processed without an error.

Comment: Is it possible that my server sent to only one registration ID but google server sent 2 times somehow and responses like this?